# how can we create scoring in iphone game 

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create score when a target is hit...

whenever a target is hit

```
int targetHit=0;
targerhit=targethit+1;
```

now I want to show that in label....

```
CCLabel* label2 = [CCLabel  labelWithString:@"null"   <-----i want to add score herer?and keep changing it ?how can i
                                         fontName:@"Marker Felt"
                                         fontSize:30];
        label2.position = ccp(400, 295);


        [self addChild:label2];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have an integer score and String scoreString associated to a CCLabel scoreLabel. These thre elements must all be attributes of your class (maybe a CCLayer).
Now, if you just want to update the scoreLabel you have to:

```
//create a range object
NSRange range;
//it starts from the first character(0) and ends at the scoreString length
range.location=0;
range.length = [scoreString length];
//then delete the characters of the string which fall in the range (that means all)
[scoreString deleteCharactersInRange:range];
//then use appendFormat to update the scoreString with the latest score value
[scoreString appendFormat:@"%07d",score];
//therefore update the label
[scoreLabel setString:scoreString];
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use cocos2d yet, but here is some info that i've found.

- (void) setString:          (NSString *)     string

  changes the string to render

  Warning:
  Changing the string is as expensive as creating a new CCLabel.